# Unifying complex objects creates unwanted nodes or tiny componded shapes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, pathfinder

[image]Please look at the image attached. We work on quite a mixed complex-shaped artworks for screen printing and we need to provide underbase/flash layer on which all color objects should be combined together to create underlay. But when we ADD multiple objects via pathfinder, it creates unwanted node/lines and few compounded shapes. Here in this image, there was a mask on the pumpkin and now we want to merge the pumpkin and mask together, but after adding them together it creates unwanted elements (circled in blue). Can you help how to get rid out of this? Using Adobe Illustrator 23.0.3.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The artwork is not "clean and aligned" correctly *before* using the Pathfinder commands.

Anchors which *should* be aligned may not be. Paths which *should* be closed may not be...

The only real solution is to ensure the artwork is clean prior to Pathfinder operations or clean it up after the Pathfinder operations.

There's no "simple and easy" trick or button. Pathfinder merely reflects the artwork construction.